# Export file is not what it should be?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I have 12 tables and I export the tables using SSIS into a existing excel file.
But the results in the excel file is not the same as the sql tables.
I'm not sure but I think the problem is when I export cause it show me this:

[image]

the table values are:

[image]

and after exporting the excel file is showing me this:

[image]

this is now the excel result, they are all correct except the first one. The service Type should be 'PS' like the rest of them but its not?
[image]

Comment: You'll have to show us expected and actual output, otherwise we'd have to guess.

Comment: @NickyvV I added the table value and excel result.

Comment: try to create a new xls file deleting manually all the rows after header, excel sometimes keeps a strange formatting and skip lines...

Comment: @alex I'm trying to put this package in a job and call it in my procedure to do all of it automatically. Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: Yes, prepare an new empty CLEAR template file (xls); place it in a folder (path1); add to your task a step to copy the file to a path (path2) useful for exports; after processing deletes the file in path2; so you can automate the process..

Comment: @alex Tnx, but i've done all this things and the only problem that I have right now is excel output which is not the same as my tables values.

Comment: excel sometimes keeps a strange formatting and skip lines, have you tried to erase the lines (all the lines in the file except header) after the header in the Excel file and run it again export?

Comment: @alex I did what you told, and it worked perfectly but now that I'm keeping the columns the data shows a few empty rows and then the values start. its not a big deal and tnx again.

Comment: Sorry, the file must be cleaned in a "brutal way" : select all rows (from the header at the end of the file), right-click and then delete ...in this way the empty rows should disappear..

Comment: @alex I suggest you to add your comments as an answer. It might be helpful for others who might run into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel sometimes keeps a strange formatting and skip lines, 
in these cases it may be necessary to prepare an empty CLEAR new template file ( xls ) by deleting the lines in a "brutal way" (select all the rows from the header at the end of the file, right-click and then delete) and run the export again.

Comment: I was checking the results right now, and the first values of the tables are not the same but the rest are ok, what would cause this? I will add a part to my question so that you can see it for your self.

Comment: are the data in the row consistent ? the system probably did not consider the order of the query..

Comment: Its not just this sheet, most of them have a same or similar problem. But some of them are ok. And in some sheet it skip a row or two.

Comment: Sorry, how many sheets have the problem of the first wrong row? you can check the correct mapping sheet..as are so many you could overlay mapping